# How to insert Git-based version in autoconf-managed project?

Tags: git, versioning, autotools, autoconf, m4

How can I assign a dynamic, git-based version number to an autoconf project?
Autoconf requires a static string argument to

```
AC_INIT([Title],[version],[name])
```

AC_INIT documentation says that one can use M4 to supply a 
shell-based version. M4 is beyond my ken. I'd like to version my 
software according to the results of this command

```
version=`git describe --abbrev=7 --dirty --always --tags`
```

This produces something like `4.6.6-alpha07-9-ga3e01a8`.

I may not understand high level answers. I need a solution like "cut
and paste this into your autoconf.ac and/or acinclude.m4".

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bumping version numbers for new releases in associated files (documentation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986521/bumping-version-numbers-for-new-releases-in-associated-files-documentation)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
AC_INIT([Title], [m4_esyscmd_s([git describe --abbrev=7 --dirty --always --tags])])
```

should work for you.

Comment: Thanks. It partially works, then causes configure to fail. Hard to figure out why. Still investigating...

Comment: @CharlieZender: Remove the `[]` around `m4_esyscmd`, and run its result thru `tr` to get rid of the trailing newline:  `AC_INIT([Title], m4_esyscmd([git describe --abbrev=7 --dirty --always --tags | tr -d '\n']))`.

Comment: This works! Configure completes with the version string I wanted. Surprised more projects don't use Git-based version tags. Not sure I should mark this answer as correct unless/until the ldav1s answer is edited ...

Comment: `tr`'s behavior is not always reliable in this situation.  See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Limitations-of-Usual-Tools.html) for more info.

Comment: Prefer `echo -n` over  `tr` to remove newlines and collapse any other whitespace into simple spaces.

Comment: According to [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Limitations-of-Builtins.html#Limitations-of-Builtins)  `printf %s` is to be preferred over `echo -n`.  The use of `m4_esyscmd_s` should render newline stripping techniques moot anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Just running `git describe` in `m4_esyscmd` for the `AC_INIT` version still leaves a few things to be desired:

- What version to use if you build a dist tarball?
  There is no `git describe` useful output to be had here at all.
- What version to use if you have just committed a change?
  Do you update the `configure` version from `git describe`,
  or just continue to build with the existing version?

For my own packages (such as [ndim-utils](https://github.com/ndim/ndim-utils)), I have solved these issues (and a few more) by

- Having a special `build-helpers/package-version` script which determines the version to use from a `version-stamp` file if found, or `git describe`. `configure.ac` `AC_INIT` will `m4_esyscmd` that script.
- Having a special `build-helpers/package-version.mk` to include from the top-level `Makefile.am` which generates a `version-stamp` file for dist tarballs, checks whether the current `git describe` output differs from what `configure` has stored, and a few other things.
- Having a `GNUmakefile.in` which updates the version stored in `configure` internals from `git describe` when necessary.

And I probably have forgotten a few issues addressed in that solution.

I am not certain that those scripts are ready to just copy over to your project, but I wanted to mention here that there are a few more things to consider.